# zIndex in React Native

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How to handle with zIndex?

I tried to specify the largest number from the scrollview, but it's still at the bottom(

[image]

Without ScrollView it looks like this, but I need to scroll up to image.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: zIndex is not supported in react-native, order that you place the elements in determines its layout order. you can try making overflow visible of scrollview.

Comment: I believe zIndex is supported in the latest version of react native for iOS only. Maybe checkout the example here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d64368b9e239b574039f4a6508bf2aeb0806121b

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the z-index but rather that the avatar view is getting clipped to the bounds of it's parent scroll view. See if you can get around this by setting the style in the scroll view as so: `<ScrollView style={{overflow =visible}} >`

Comment: @Abhishek zIndex is available now. Check release notes of version 0.29 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.29.0

Comment: @brien.crean for Android too, but only in version 0.30 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3d3b067f6fc831b6b23726087fe39cf39ef86f00

Comment: @IvoDimitrov oh, didn't knew about that. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been implemented in iOS as of 0.30 (see the [commit changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d64368b9e239b574039f4a6508bf2aeb0806121b)) and in android in 0.31 ([changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3d3b067f6fc831b6b23726087fe39cf39ef86f00))

I have made a simple example component for how I have been using it:

```
'use-strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
const { View, StyleSheet } = require('react-native');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex:1,
    },
    back: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        zIndex: 0
    },
    front: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top:25,
        left:25,
        width: 50,
        height:50,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        zIndex: 1
    }
});

class Layers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <View style={styles.back}></View>
                <View style={styles.front}></View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Layers;
```

Comment: So in your example if you reverse the order you load the 'back' and 'front' elements does the zIndex still play nicely? I only ask cause now you have them loading back to front so it would work regardless of zIndex, right?

Comment: You are correct that if you reverse the order they will still be in the intended z-index. You might be thinking that the order of appearance might change the layering, but View works very similar to html Div in the sense that they aren't draw on the screen as layers, but end up being stacked from top to bottom

Comment: Note: this only works on iOS when the elements are [siblings](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#zindex).

Comment: the main issue that i have faced is i am using the position on directly button or any image... that's why i am not getting the proper result... thanks man... this helps me a lot...